# web3.Keypair.fromSeed issues

Tags: solana-web3js

This used to work for me :

```
const mnemonic = Bip39.generateMnemonic()
const key = derivePath(
        `m/44'/501'/0'/0'`,
        Bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic).toString("hex")
    ).key

const pair = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(key.toString())
```

But now I get:

```
TypeError: unexpected type, use Uint8Array
    at checkArrayTypes (/Users/ttt/dev/rrr/TOKENPASS/tpass-graphql/graphql/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2165:13)
    at Function.fromSecretKey (/Users/ttt/dev/rrr/TOKENPASS/tpass-graphql/graphql/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2318:3)
    at Function.fromSecretKey (/Users/ttt/dev/rrr/TOKENPASS/tpass-graphql/graphql/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/keypair.ts:64:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

const key = derivePath(
`m/44'/501'/0'/0'`,
Bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic).toString("hex")
).privateKey

const pair = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(key)

try this